# Add bool variable to int

Tags: c++, casting

I have in my code a boolean function "lookup" which has the parameter byte: lookup(byte). My variable _size is an integer. Is it good practice to do stuff like following:

```
_size += !lookup(byte);
```

I mean the point is the  implicit  cast from bool and int. Otherwise I have to do something like this

```
if (!lookup(byte)) {
  _size++;
}
```

but I thought that would be less efficient.

Comment: _"Is it good practice to do stuff like following"_ It's opinion based.

Comment: The second version seems clearer and therefore better for long-term maintenance of the code.  I'd trust the compiler to optimize both versions.

Comment: I would do it a different way `_size += lookup(byte) ? 0 : 1;` but it's a matter of taste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `!lookup(byte)` is guaranteed to have one of the values, `true` or `false`. When used as an `int`, these are converted to `1` and `0` respectively.

So the following 2 snippets:

```
_size += !lookup(byte); // true -> add 1, false -> add 0
```

and

```
if (!lookup(byte)) {  // if true
  _size++;            // add 1
}
```

are equivalent.
You should pick whichever one is easier to read, and understand. The compiler is going to generate the same assembly for both versions, so you don't have to worry about efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in efficiency. Compilers apply optimizations and the outcome of both is likely exactly the same.

If you want to make the conversion more explicit you could use a `static_cast`:

```
_size += static_cast<size_t>(!lookup(byte));
```